# New line in Javascript confirmation message

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I've a .Net application wherein one of my pages, during initial page load, I'm setting the text of an asp label control. In my aspx page, I've a Javascript function to read the label text and show a confirmation pop-up message. The problem is, "\n" with in the label text is not introducing a line break in the JS confirmation message.

**My Code Behind**

```c#
lblMsg.Text = "string1" + "\n" + "string2"
```

**Aspx Page**

```js
function PendingDeleteValidate() {
    var x = document.getElementById("<%=lblMsg.ClientID%>");

    if (confirm(x.innerHTML))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

The JS confirmation dialog message shows:

> string1\nstring2

I need to show a line break between the two strings.

Comment: Does the confirmation dialog have to get its text from a label? The problem is you're using `innerHTML` and `window.confirm` doesn't know what to do with the HTML. It reads the `\n` as just two characters like any others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set like this in code behind:

```
lblMsg.Text = "string1" + "<br/>" + "string2"
```

And this

```
if (confirm(x.innerHTML))
```

to this

```
if (confirm(x.innerText))
```

Comment: It didn't work. Confirmation message shows up as string1<BR>string2

Comment: Yup. Just tried innerText and it worked. Thank you!. Also,Thanks Mike for explaining why innerHTML doesn't work.

Comment: `textContent` should be used: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.textContent

Comment: innerText is not crossbrowser friendly!

Answer (score 5):

Try `"\r\n \r\n"` after title text.

```
function myFunction() {
    confirm("Tittle of DialogBox \r\n \r\nMessage of dialogbox. bla..bla.. bla... bla... bla..");
}
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/patelriki13/wfdLo7ts/)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

why not try this i always use it

> \\n
>   also it would be wise to replace \r with ""

like this , have fun

and if you are only showing alerts with javascript then here is my function:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("alert('");
sb.Append(msg.Replace("\n", "\\n").Replace("\r", "").Replace("'", "\\'"));
sb.Append("');");
return sb.ToString();
```

see if it works your needs.
Regards